# What is the best GUI builder for swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am using Netbeans IDE for creating my swing GUIs but most of the time I face hard to create a good looking GUI by dragging swing components around. I've heard that some people suggest building swing GUI by coding is it true? or are there any better GUI builders for swing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swing+builder

Comment: _that some people suggest building swing GUI by coding_ ... is this really such a shock ?

Comment: Robin, imho Swing is as ill-suited for handcoding as for interactive methods, similar to how XML is ill-suited for both reading by humans and parsing by computers. Due to the sheer amount of time it takes to create and edit a Swing window layout I resorted to prototyping with WPF so I have to Swing it only once ;-)

Comment: `What is the best GUI builder for swing` none of them, because in most cases is too hard to override (modifyied Component back to) basic and important AWT & Swing methods

Comment: Any GUI builder you see that generates and maintains Java code directly, instead of having a declarative layout format from which Java code is produced, will always fail to be useful for anything beyond Hello, World. Plus, Swing has flexible layout managers that are not based on arranging the components on an X-Y grid, but on defining quite complex and interacting *constraints* on the components. It really is better to code directly (although by no means easy -- like @Joey said :)

Answer (score 4):

NetBeans is one of the best IDEs which support easy and off the shelf GUI generation.

You can specify the layout manager to be used and it writes code for you.  For instance, set the layout manager as GridBagConstraints.  Simply drag & drop swing components, it will write statement with appropriate GridBagConstraints.

Answer (score 1):

[WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). Integrates much better with handwritten code in my opinion.